# Smartsheet Sync for Google Forms times out

Tags: runtime-error, smartsheet-api, executiontimeout

I'm getting an error for a survey that has about 90 questions but only 10 respondents when I try to use the Smartsheet Sync add on.  Error says that it"Exceeds Maximum Execution Time".  How can I increase the execution time so that it will add responses to my Smartsheet? I don't know anything about coding.  I'm not evens sure if I could edit the add-on?  Please advise.

Comment: Hi Sheri, This sounds like an issue with your specific form, and the Smartsheet support team would be happy to help you troubleshoot. Reach out to them through this form, and they will help you figure out what the issue is: https://help.smartsheet.com/contact

Comment: Hi thanks for your response; however Smartsheet wasn't able to help or is choosing not to.  They said to make my form smaller which I cannot do because the survey is collecting responses.  Is there any way to edit the add on to extend the execution time?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing your form with me, so that I could take a closer look. It appears that your form actually contains 96 sections each with multiple questions. When you create a Google Sheet for the form responses, 361 columns are created.

This is probably the cause of your issue. Each sheet in Smartsheet can only handle around 200 columns per sheet, and Smartsheet Sync automatically tries to create a column for each question in your Google Form. It appears you have uncovered a bug where our error messaging in Smartsheet Sync could be better - informing the user that the form has more questions than a sheet can handle, rather than trying to create the sheet and then timing out. We will make a note of this bug so that we can address it in a future revision.

As it stands, Smartsheet would not be able to handle a form with 361 questions, so it doesn't appear that Smartsheet Sync will be able to handle this form.

Comment: It would have been nice to know that before I designed the survey.  Thanks for looking at it.